# How to parse a column while referring to values from other multiple columns?

Tags: r, function, loops, dplyr

I have this sample dataframe where column a to d are reference columns and column `x1-3` need to be parsed and plugged with new values.

Here is the code to re-produce the data frame:

```
    df1 <- data_frame(a = c(0,1,0,1), b = c(0,0,1,1), c = c(0,0,0,0), d = 
      c(1,0,0,1), x1= c(NA, NA, NA, NA), x2= c(NA, NA, NA, NA), x3= c(NA, NA, NA, NA))
```

[image]

I want to give new values to `x1 -x3` based on different value combination from column `a, b, c, d`. My pseudocode is as follows:

```
    for df1[ , "x1"]:
        if a = 1: then return 1
        else: return 0
    for df1[ , "x2"]: 
        if a = 1 & b = 1: then return 1
        else: return 0
    for df1[ , "x3"]: 
        all conditions: return 1
```

Ideally, all the values in `x1` and `x2` will be changed according to their given conditions. `X3` should be filled with `1` no matter what. Can anyone suggest a efficient way to loop & parse through those columns, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need loops:

```
df1$x1 <- df1$a
df1$x2 <- as.integer(df1$a & df1$b)
df1$x3 <- 1
```

Result:

```
  a b c d x1 x2 x3
1 0 0 0 1  0  0  1
2 1 0 0 0  1  0  1
3 0 1 0 0  0  0  1
4 1 1 0 1  1  1  1
```

***Edit:***

If columns a-d are not binary values (0 or 1) you still can use the same expressions to create columns x1-3. Let's say you have this data frame:

```
  a b c d x1 x2 x3
1 0 0 1 5 NA NA NA
2 3 9 2 1 NA NA NA
3 4 2 3 5 NA NA NA
4 2 1 4 1 NA NA NA
```

And your conditions are:

```
x1 = 1 if (b >= 2) and (d < 4) 0 otherwise
x2 = 1 if (a > b) and (b < d) 0 otherwise
x3 = always 1
```

You can use the same methodology:

```
df1$x1 <- as.integer(df1$b >= 2 & df1$d < 4)
df1$x2 <- as.integer(df1$a > df1$b & df1$b < df1$d)
df1$x3 <- 1
```

Result:

```
  a b c d x1 x2 x3
1 0 0 1 5  0  0  1
2 3 9 2 1  1  0  1
3 4 2 3 5  0  1  1
4 2 1 4 1  0  0  1
```

Comment: Thanks for this simple and elegant solution. Although it is my original question, I do want to further this question by imaging the case that a, b, c, are not `0` or `1` but other integers such as `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, must I use a function to loop? Thanks again!

Comment: @EdwardLin I edited my answer with your new conditions, hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @CharlesMitjans, this is very helpful and again an elegant solution.